# Instantiation of ASP.NET Core application in production

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core starts executing from `Main` method which lies in `Program class` inside `Program.cs` file. That builds a web hosting environment and tell that web host to start running. Then, there is `startup.cs` file.

When developing a .NET Core web application, I have to build it locally (by Ctrl-F5 for example). When doing that, `Main` method is running. Every next time I want to open my web application, given IIS Express has already been launched, I am just writing e.g. http://localhost:65040. By doing that, `Main` method **is not running** again, but everything works fine (routing etc..). So, ***I have the following question***:

How .NET Core knows what to do upon the reception of the above Http request (http://localhost:65040)? For example, how does it implement routing since

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
})
```

in `Startup.cs` is not running again? `There is no need for that because IIS has already been informed?`

And if the above thought is correct what exactly is happening in `deployment`? Then our Http requests never trigger `program.cs` and `startup.cs`. **So, in which way the remote web server is being informed about stuff how to implement routing etc?**

Comment: Web applications don't have a `Program.cs` unless you're doing self-hosting (via OWIN et al.).

Comment: Think you've got it the wrong way round. IIS (and IISExpress) act as a shim between the network and your application, unless you're self-hosting, and forwards requests to your application.

Comment: @KennethK., you have it in asp.net core, because it's actually console application.

Comment: @Alexan The question didn't say anything about Core when I posted my comment :)

Comment: @Alexan The question didn't say anything about Core when I posted my comment :)

Comment: @KennethK., but now it says.

Comment: @KennethK, not necessary, the code says it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a lot of studying and experiments, I found that the key point into my answer is the following:
`Program.cs` and  `Startup.cs` are running **only the very first time** an Http request is being made. It is this first time which configures `Kestrel` and informs it about everything it has to know for any subsequent request (e.g. routing).

To be honest, I do not know *how exactly the application distinguishes between the very first request and the other ones*, however what I described above is definitely happening to both development and production.

Comment: This answer is wrong. `Program.cs` codes run when application starts (there is no HTTP request yet). There is no difference between the first request and others. You really need to study how .NET Core works to  understand the flow of a .NET Core application.

Comment: @Sasan, the answer is **correct**. My actual query was how on earth the application starts. No one gave an answer to that. You are writing `Program.cs runs when application starts`. But you say nothing about **when**. So when, is the first request definitely. You can check that by using IIS Manager where you can add in Sites a local folder published  application. Then you can see that the very first Http request executes `Main()`. A check I used is to add `File.AppendAllText("log.txt", "Hello world");` inside Main method.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. You most likely confused by playing locally with IIS express. If you run your program by clicking Ctrl-F5 from Visual Studio IDE it launches your application by issuing `dotnet <your_app>.dll` command and launches IIS Express that plays a role of reverse proxy. By default the Visual Studio IDE also opens a browser for you what creates the impression that first request initiated application to launch. This is not true. To prove it run your app with no IIS express as shown [here](http://prntscr.com/iqlf3c).

Comment: Also go to project properties, Debug and switch of the `Launch browser` checkbox. Now you will have a full control on all requests coming to your application. Now if you set a breakpoint in `Main` method and run the app by clicking F5 you will see the breakpoint will be hit immediately after application started even there are no any requests sent to your application yet.

Comment: @AlexeyAndrushkevich, then what about your answer at         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235165/how-exactly-an-asp-net-core-web-application-is-launched ? There, you agreed with my assumption and here you reject it... And if you are right, **who will launch the application once deployed**? I made some experiments with  IIS Manager for a locally  deployed (into a folder) application and I am 100% sure the very first Http request launches the application...

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper my answer doesn't contradict to what I've said here. You are running your ASP.NET Core application on IIS/IIS Express which take care of some details hiding them from you. Indeed it is very possible that IIS doesn't run the application immediately after it has been added to the list of apps and prefers to wait for a real request to the app so that to not keep the app in memory for no reasons. With other web servers you must run `dotnet <your_app>.dll` manually what in fact starts the application.

Comment: Therefore, my answer is correct! Please, undo your down vote as well.

Answer (score 6):

Regardless of hosting you choose for ASP.Net Core Application (IIS or self hosting via Kestrel), methods `Program.Main()`, `Startup.ConfigureServices()` and `Startup.Configure()` are executed exactly once during hosting process startup.

It's obvious that `Program.Main()` is executed when you launch exe file with Kestrel web server within. It could be however not obvious whether it's actually called when hosting in IIS. It is so actually. When ASP.Net Core Application is integrated with IIS, it's usually executed by dotnet.exe runner (it's also possible to configure the launch of application .exe file). You could check it in web.config created during adding of application:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- ... -->
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\TestMvcApplication.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So it basically the same as when you run application with command `dotnet.exe TestMvcApplication.dll`. `Program.Main()` is executed in this case, with `Startup` methods following.

Without `Main()` method that basically builds the web host, ASP.Net Core application just can not run.

When you fire subsequent queries, they are processed by the same hosting application (I mean the same Windows process here). And all configuration required by ASP.Net Core (like routing, middleware, services etc.) is already wired up within this process. That's why ASP.Net Core is able to process the requests.

I hope this is an answer for your question. Here are some useful links that could be helpful:

[Hosting in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

[Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

[Application startup in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup)

Answer (score 3):

Here's what happens when you run your program from a high level view:

First like any other .NET application the Main method will be called, since that's the starting point in any .NET application.

If it's a console app then nothing special, it just runs the codes and exits the program.

But for web applications the program needs to run forever and listen to incoming HTTP requests. So how can we say to our app to do this for us? We have to configure it. Like any other framework, .NET Core has some rules and conventions, here's the simplest way you can build a web app in .NET Core:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .Configure(app =>
            {
                app.Run(async context => await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!"));
            })
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }
}
```

So what happens here is that the OS runs the `Main` method in a process (with a processing thread). We create a `WebHostBuilder` and configure it to use Kestrel as webserver and send back "Hello World!" string to any incoming HTTP request.
Then we build and run our `WebHostBuilder`.

What `Configure` method does is that it creates a pipeline so every request will go through the logic of that pipeline. All the method you see in the `Configure` method will just add extra logic to the pipeline like authentication, static content serving, configuring routes and etc.

I should note here that for using some features we have to add them to our program first, which will be done in `ConfigureServices()` method, which runs before `Configure()` method.

The important method here is `Run()`, which blocks the calling thread (the thread that called the `Main` method). So the `Main` method will never complete, otherwise it would exit the program. But our `WebHost` is running in the background and will respond to HTTP requests.

So to wrap up, the `Main` method will run only once during the application startup and it creates and configures a `WebHost` to serve the HTTP requests. There is no need to run the `Main` method or create a new `WebHost` for every request.

These were some basics, if you want to learn more you should read Microsoft Docs. There are many useful informations there.

Comment: What about a remote web server? Do you know the mechanism which executes Main() as to make the application responsive to Http requests?

Comment: Well if you mean how IIS and nginx and Apache communicate with Kestrel, that's done with a reverse proxy which means IIS for example receives the request first, does its job on the request and then pass it to the Kestrel (Again I recommend to read the docs). But if you mean how IIS and Kestrel work behind the scenes, that's serious low-level stuff which is beyond my knowledge

Comment: What I mean is who triggers Main() ? Locally, this is done by Ctrl-F5 for example. By that, the WebHost is built. I cannot still understand how this is done remotely. When we deploy our project e.g. in Azure, somehow Main() has to be executed in the remote environment, isn't it? But , how?

Comment: Eventually dotnet.exe runner is launched which executes application in the same way as if it is executed on your local machine. It does not matter where the web application is running, it is always launched inside some process. And when that process starts, `Main` method is executed that results to ASP.Net Core setup.

Comment: Whoever hosts the app will trigger `Main`. Publishing an ASP.NET Core app means telling a server (local, Azure, whatever) that this is my executable, run it for me. The process is the same.