# How exactly an ASP. NET core web application is launched

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am developing an `ASP.NET Core web application` with Visual Studio 2017. After publishing the project (e.g. in Azure), I know that `Main()` method in `Program.cs` is invoked only the **very first time** we send an Http request to the corresponding server. Actually, that is when the application is **launched**. Every subsequent request does not invoke the above method. I have some queries upon the above:

- My guess is that launching is in fact running `dotnet <app_name>.dll`. *Am I right*?
- How the subsequent requests know the application has already been launched? By which mechanism are they informed?
- How `dotnet` command is known to the remote server? Does the deployment care about that and copies the appropriate files to the server?

Comment: Should we assume that you are talking about an Azure App Service website? (i.e an IIS-backed ASP.NET Core site)

Comment: Exactly that. Yes

Comment: Well, then you are looking for [the IIS module that handles ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration), (and most likely [Kestrel](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer) as well)

Comment: Your assumption that `Main` is executed for the first HTTP request is likely faulty. The website is started and launched within the webserver it is running in. The webserver (IIS) will handle incoming HTTP requests and pass them through to the launched web application.

Comment: Definitely, it is not faulty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My guess is that launching is in fact running `dotnet <app_name>.dll`. Am I right?

Yes, you are right. IIS has the [ASP.NET Core Module (ANCM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module) which is responsible for proxying requests from IIS to a backend ASP.NET Core application running Kestrel. So yes in fact it does call `dotnet <your_app>.dll` in the background when the application is started and the `Main` method is invoked once exactly at that time. Once the process is started IIS just proxying incoming requests to it.

> How the subsequent requests know the application has already been launched? By which mechanism are they informed?

Not sure for 100% but I can guess that ANCM tries to connect to ASP.NET Core Application over HTTP and in case the remote app doesn't respond it just tries to run it with `dotnet <your_app>.dll` one more time.

> How `dotnet` command is known to the remote server? Does the deployment care about that and copies the appropriate files to the server?

Yes. When you publish your ASP.NET Core application by running `dotnet publish -o <publish_folder>` note the `web.config` file that was created automatically on publish. This file is used to configure ANCM and provides it with information about `<your_app>.dll` and `dotnet` command.

This is going to change (ensuring forward and backward compatibility) with ASP.NET Core 2.1. For more information look at [ASP.NET Core 2.1.0-preview1: Improvements to IIS hosting](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/28/asp-net-core-2-1-0-preview1-improvements-to-iis-hosting/)

Comment: What about if the remote web server is not IIS ? It could be Apache for example.

Comment: Apache/Nginx/HaProxy can be setup as reverse proxy and forward all requests to a backend ASP.NET Core application as well. So the behavior is the same except the fact that you have to manually setup them to work together. Because IIS is the MS's product they take care about integration with it and provide some tools which work out of the box. Take a look at [Web server implementations in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?tabs=aspnetcore2x) for more information on how to run ASP.NET Core with different web servers.

Comment: It sounds like you are missing the point that ASP.NET Core application comes with built-in web server Kestrel. So when you run `dotnet <your_app>.dll` it actually runs the Kestrel and starts hosting you app. So technically you don't need another web server to host it, but practically the Kestrel is very limited and doesn't have all functionality that such well-known web servers as IIS, Apache and Nginx have. This is why MS recommends to setup these web servers as reverse proxies for production use.

Comment: I asked you to undo the unfair down vote at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49033299/instantiation-of-asp-net-core-application-in-production

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper I didn't downvote you, I just commented why I think that your answer is wrong.